# Coldfusion 10 Dynamic Select from Microsoft SQL

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, coldfusion

I have some issues created a dynamic dropdown select menu in ColdFusion. I'd like to populate the select menu based on the date entered through the JQuery DatePicker (SpeakDate). However, I'm getting an issue where it says the SpeakDate in my query is undefined in my form. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
    </script>

    <cfquery name="getAgenda" 
        datasource="SpeakerCard"> 
        SELECT ItemNo 
        FROM tbl_AgendaList
        WHERE MeetingDate = '(#Form.SpeakDate#)'
    </cfquery> 
</head>

<cfoutput>
    <cfform id="Form" action="Card.cfm" method="post"> 
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="SpeakDate"><p>

    <p>Agenda Item: 
    <cfselect query="getAgenda"
        name="ItemNo" 
        value="ItemNo"> 
    </cfselect>
    </cfform>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: You can't do that. Coldusion runs on server long before any date is selected in browser. You could send the date to server using ajax and have the `<option>` html returned. If you are relaoding this same page as part of form submit ... need to check first if `#Form.SpeakDate#` exists before running the query

Comment: In other words, you can't access form scoped variables until you submit the form.

Comment: I see... So if I use ajax, the database query would be sent after the date has been picked?

Comment: This might be a useful read, so as to understand how the client & the CFML server interact (hint: they don't): http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html

Answer (score 0):

This is far from an optimal solution, however it might produce the result you are looking for.

```
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
<cfif structKeyExists(Form,"SpeakDate")>
    <cfquery name="getAgenda" 
        datasource="SpeakerCard"> 
        SELECT ItemNo 
        FROM tbl_AgendaList
        WHERE MeetingDate = '(#Form.SpeakDate#)'
    </cfquery>
</cfif>
</head>

<cfoutput>
<cfform id="Form" action="Card.cfm" method="post"> 
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="SpeakDate"><p>

<p>Agenda Item: 
<cfif isDefined("getAgenda")>
    <cfselect query="getAgenda"
        name="ItemNo" 
        value="ItemNo"> 
    </cfselect>
</cfif>
</cfform>
```